# How can I associate ".js.php" to JavaScript Syntax in the NetBeans 6.5 IDE?

Tags: netbeans

When I generate CSS or JavaScript files using PHP I like to use .js.php or .css.php file extensions. so that I know what's going on.

Is there a way of associating these "compound" file extensions to their respective languages?

Comment: Still have this problem with netbeans 7.0

Answer (score 7):

I don't use NetBeans or PHP, but the following trick helped me in a similar setting:

```
<?php if(0) { ?><script><?php } ?>
# code goes here
<?php if(0) { ?></script><?php } ?>
```

Simply surround the js code with `<script>` or `<style>` tags that don't get rendered. No need to configure any special associations, assuming the editor is smart enough about HTML.

Comment: dirty hack, but +1, nevertheless

Comment: I generate .js files with php, in that case I always forgot to remove <script> :-D

Comment: NetBeans 8.1 released, but better solution is not exists still :(

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is condense such "compound" extensions into one, following the tradition of condensing .tar.gz into .tgz.